# MySQL has multiple orders by, one of which is empty, and the value is not expected

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

sql version:8.0

sql ：

```
  CREATE TABLE `t_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sale_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `join_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `t_test`(`id`, `user_id`, `status`, `sale_time`, `join_time`) VALUES (1, 1, '1', NULL, '2022-02-01 17:59:45');
INSERT INTO `t_test`(`id`, `user_id`, `status`, `sale_time`, `join_time`) VALUES (2, 1, '0', NULL, '2022-02-17 18:00:07');
INSERT INTO `t_test`(`id`, `user_id`, `status`, `sale_time`, `join_time`) VALUES (3, 1, '1', NULL, '2022-02-16 18:00:19');
INSERT INTO `t_test`(`id`, `user_id`, `status`, `sale_time`, `join_time`) VALUES (4, 2, '1', '2022-02-17 18:02:14', '2022-02-17 18:02:17');
INSERT INTO `t_test`(`id`, `user_id`, `status`, `sale_time`, `join_time`) VALUES (5, 2, '1', '2022-02-08 18:02:26', '2022-02-17 18:02:30');
```

table data:
[image]

and my SQL query statement：

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM `t_test` 
      ORDER BY `status` desc ,sale_time desc,join_time desc)A 
GROUP BY A.user_id
```

and the sql result：
[image]

My requirement is to sort by status first, and then by sale_ time, and finally by join_ time sort.If sale_time is null use join_time instead

Obviously, according to the first diagram and sorting rules, user_ Id = 1 should be id = 3

So what is the method to continue to arrange the next sort field when a sort is empty

So does anyone here know how to do this?

Comment: (1) ORDER BY specified in subquery is always lost in outer query. (2) Your GROUP BY is partial/incomplete and cannot produce deterministic output. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and fix your query. (3) Post the task itself, not only your attempt to solve. (4) Post sample data as INSERT INTO, not as a picture. Post desired output which completely matches the sample data.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The insert data has been completed

Comment: *My requirement is to sort by status first* ASC? DESC?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( 
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id 
                              ORDER BY join_time DESC, id DESC) rn
              FROM t_test 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9be3bcb568696357fc96671cac548a3b

---

> My requirement is to sort by status first, and then by sale_ time, and finally by join_ time sort.If sale_time is null use join_time instead

Use according expression in the window definition:

```
ORDER BY status [DESC], 
         COALESCE(sale_time, join_time) [DESC],
         join_time [DESC]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you give me a complete answer

Comment: @jane "complete answer" - what do you mean? If something is not clear then ask precise question. PS. fiddle added.

Comment: Your SQL statement still can't solve my problem. My requirement is to sort by status first, and then by sale_ time, and finally by join_ time sort, when sale_time is empty,  will continue to be used join_time sorting, obviously, according to the first diagram and sorting rules, user_ Id = 1 should be id = 3

Comment: @jane *My requirement is to sort by status first* You have not told this explicitly (you have not described the criteria at all). No problems - adjust ORDER BY expression in the widow definition according to your needs. PS. Add this complete explanation into the question text.

Comment: @jane *then by sale_time, and finally by join_time sort, when sale_time is empty, will continue to be used join_time sorting* Unclear. If sale_time is null use join_time instead? or put/sort the rows with non-null sale_time first, and with null - after, with secondary sorting by join_time?

Comment: sorry,My fault, I have added a complete description

Comment: You are really a rigorous teacher,thank you@Akina

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242107/discussion-between-jane-and-akina).

Comment: its that:WITH cte AS ( 
SELECT *, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id 
ORDER BY status [DESC], 
COALESCE(sale_time, join_time) [DESC], 
join_time [DESC]) rn 
FROM t_test 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1                                                                                                              
 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: Square brackets means that I don't know does this modifier is needed or not. You must either remove sq. brackets or remove ordering modifier at all.